# What word should I use for someone who has been around for a while?

Tags: nouns

When I say 'Been around for a while' I mean like someone who has been somewhere, or been a member for a while. I'm trying to make a role for the people in my discord server for some of the oldest members, you see.

Comment: When you say "oldest members", do you mean the members who are the most aged, or the members who have been part of the community for the longest?

Comment: There is an almost endless range of terms that can be used, taken from different areas. It depends if you're wanting something dignified or humorous, elevated or insulting. Often for servers/forums/etc something specific to the area under discussion is used.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be **longtimer,** [defined by MW as:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/longtimer)

> one that has been in a place, position, or activity for a long time